# React API call outside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was curious to know if making an `API` request outside of the **lifecycle/useEffect** is a valid way to make the call?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-useeffect-button has two functional components, the parent component makes an `API` call and passes the data to the `child component`, initially specified the limit of data to be fetched from the endpoint as 2 and the parent component has a `LoadMore` function that is passed as a `prop` along with the data to the `child component`.

Using the `react-slick slider` to display the images in the `child component` and the Load button `onClick` will call the function `LoadMore` inside the parent component and then it makes an API call and appends the new data from API to the old Data. The load button will append one Image to the existing images.

is this a good way to make API requests or should it be done only in the lifecycle methods?

Comment: NO, If you do so, your api call will run as infinite loop. Test it and check the network tab

Comment: I checked the network tab and it just calls one API for each onClick callback

Comment: Yes for onClick, it's fine because you make every call when user click on button. But for initial fetching, if you move your code from use effect to outside, it will run infinitely

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is this a good way to make API requests outside useEffect/lifecycle.?

It depends on your requirements.

> should it be done only in the lifecycle methods?

It depends on your requirements.

---

There's nothing wrong making API request outside useEffect. *But* it should be done in some other function or it will cause the request to go on every re-render. 
And if the response if being saved in a state variable.

Then it will go into the infinite loop.

> When do we make the request in useEffect and when by some other function?

Requests that fetch data or send some info at the time of initialization of the component is supposed to be made in componentDidMount/useEffect

And requests that are supposed to be sent on some action (like in your case, onClick) so they are hit according to that event.

**There's neither good or bad, it's all about your requirements.**

Comment: if you look at the stackblitz code, the Loadmore function is only called on the click and not on the initial render or the following rerender after appending the state.  I removed the arrow function for the button callback and then it went into an infinite loop.

Comment: after removing the arrow function, I think you're calling the function in the onClick event like `onClick{func()}` that causing the req. to go in an infinite loop. Just pass the function. `onClick{func}`.

Again this is I'm just assuming, or you can edit to show your code.

Comment: ah, I see the issue, when using the arrow syntax we need to call the func() and when it is not using => we have to make the reference to the func?

Comment: Yes. You just need to pass the function, the child will call it.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your needs.

if you think whenever your params change,API call will be triggered.
   in this case, you should set the API call inside the useEffect.

If you want your API call triggered on page load(ComponentDidMount). In this case, you should set API call inside the useEffect

Otherwise no need to set api call inside useEffect.

**In your case no need to set API call inside useEffect**. because you hit the API call when the user clicks the button. So no need to use useEffect.

Answer (score 2):

If you are making an API call to get data from initial render then using a lifecycle hook is a good approach. In your scenario, you want to make an API request when hitting a button. In that case it can be a simple function without any lifecycle hook method.

The only key part here is that you are maintaining the state and rendering the view from the state.